# Write-Host works in my script, but Write and Write-Output break it

Tags: powershell

I've been using `Write-Host` in my script, but I want this text to appear in an output file, so I've tried changing it to `Write` or `Write-Output`. When I do this, part of my code crashes. I don't understand why.

I'd also like to see output on the console as the script runs, not just in the file.

This code works

```
function Load-Configuration([string] $ConfigurationFileName)
{
    $ConfigurationFilePath = Join-Path -Path $ScriptFileFolder -ChildPath $ConfigurationFileName
    Write-Host "Configuration file is located here: $ConfigurationFilePath"
    if(Test-Path -Path $ConfigurationFilePath)
    {
        . $ConfigurationFilePath
    }
    else
    {
        Throw "Configuration file `"$ConfigurationFilePath`" not found."
    }
}
```

But crashes with Write-Output,

```
function Load-Configuration([string] $ConfigurationFileName)
{
    $ConfigurationFilePath = Join-Path -Path $ScriptFileFolder -ChildPath $ConfigurationFileName
    Write-Output "Configuration file is located here: $ConfigurationFilePath"
    if(Test-Path -Path $ConfigurationFilePath)
    {
        . $ConfigurationFilePath
    }
    else
    {
        Throw "Configuration file `"$ConfigurationFilePath`" not found."
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Property 'BuildDestination' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.
At C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\eSignAutoDeploy\eSignUpgradeScript.ps1:43 char:4
+ if(!(Test-Path -Path $Config.BuildDestination)){
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict
```

Comment: Your error does not match your code. The `write-output` is not what it is complaining about but `$Config.BuildDestination`. I don't even see a `$config` in you code examples. Your code appears fine. Error is from an earlier build maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Do you process the output of Load-Configuration in any way?  If so, you just added a string to the output of the function that you need to account for. For this type of output, I usually use `Write-Verbose`. Most of the time I don't want to see verbose information but when I do, I just slap on a -Verbose parameter.  And this sort of verbose output doesn't get mixed up with the std output. To make this work, declare your function like so:

```
function Load-Configuration([Parameter()][string] $ConfigurationFileName)
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
Load-Configuration config.xml -verbose
```